# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined (strapi)

Tags: node.js, react, e-commerce

Estou criando um eCommerce usando o Strapi, porém estou com um problema em uma das rotas que faz o POST. Resumindo essa rota ela abre uma sessão de pagamento, e para isso eu passo um `request.body` com o tipo de produto que vai ser comprado, o método chamado para isso é o `findOne()`. Porém, quando faço a requisição, ao invés de vir a resposta, esta vindo `undefined`.

Segue aqui o código:

```
async create(ctx) {

    const {
        product
    } = ctx.request.body

    if (!product) {
        return ctx.throw(400, 'please especiefiede de product')
    }

    const realProduct = await strapi.services.product.findOne({
        id: product.id
    })
    if (!realProduct) {
        return ctx.throw(404, 'No product with such id')
    }


    const {
        user
    } = ctx.state
    const BASE_URL = ctx.request.headers.origin || 'http:localhost:3000'

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        costumer_email: user.email,
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${BASE_URL}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: BASE_URL,
        line_items: [{
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'brl',
                    product_data: {
                        name: realProduct.meProd
                    },
                    unit_amount: fromDecimalToInt(realProduct.price),
                },
                quatity: 1
            }

        ]
    })

    //aqui criar a ordem
    const newOrder = await stripe.services.order.create({
        user: user.id,
        product: realProduct.id,
        total: realProduct.price,
        status: 'unpaid',
        checkout_session: session.id

    })

    return {
        id: session.id
    }

}
```

O que importa vai apenas até o `realProduct`.

Comment: De acordo com a mensagem de errom `strapi.services` não tem essa propriedade `product`. Está muito dificil entender o contexto do código sem mais referências. Poderia compartilhar o link da documentacao do Strapi onde voce usar esse recurso `strapi.services`, ou mostrar mais do código?

Comment: Então, esse é o problema, o products foi definido mais acima, ele recebe o ctx.request.body,ou seja são os dados da requisição que eu passo. O que não entendo e o por que de estar dando undefined uma vez que a váriavel já ta definida

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/concepts/controllers.html#concept

aqui a documentação de como implementar o controller da API

Comment: Tipo, ele não ta caindo na excessão que me gera o 400 ou 404,Ele recebe a request

E o contexto, eu já tenho uma API feita no strapi, e essa function, configura um POST que inicia uma sessão de Pagamento a Partir do produto solicitado na request